# Probability that in fully connected graph there is a clique of different colors

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Actually I got this question in job interview and successfully failed it ( it was obvious eliminating question ). I recall the Ramsey theory and cited the famous result on *existence* of cliques with edges of same color.
But they then asked me to discuss how to estimate the probability that in fully connected graph there is a clique where edge colors are all *different*?
Namely, they said: "Imagine that in a fully-connected graph, each *edge* is painted with one of two colours. Estimate the probability that the graph contains a fully-connected subgraph on 3 vertices that has edges of different colours"

I read a lot of articles but it does not look as naive result, which anyone knows since college graduation.
So any help/hints/links are highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a triangle where **all colors are different**, then you obviously don't have enough different colors for that when there are only $2$ colors, so the probability is $0$.

If you're looking for a triangle where **both colors are represented**, then such a triangle will automatically exists unless *all* edges in the original graph have the same color.

Namely, suppose that $(v_1,v_2)$ is black and $(v_3,v_4)$ is white. If $(v_2,v_3)$ is black, then $\{v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is a triangle that has both a black and a white edge; otherwise $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is such a triangle. (And if the two edges already share a vertex, just $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ will do).

Thus the probability we're looking for is
$$ 1 - 2^{-\binom{n}{2}+1} $$
which, when $n$ is not very small, will be so close to $1$ as not to matter.

---

Things get more involved with different numbers than $2$ colors and $3$-cliques, but it doesn't sound like that was what you were asked.

Comment: Great, thank you! :-) If your reasoning was based on anything but common sense then please share relevant literature for refreshment. Case when there are more than 2 colors and 3-cliques is especially interesting

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on formula? It's not very intuitive for me...

Comment: @VastAcademician: There are $\binom n2$ edges in the graph. The probability that they are all black is $2^{-\binom n2}$. The probability that they are all whit is $2^{-\binom n2}$. The probability that they are all _the same color_ is the sum of these (since "all black" and "all white") are mutually exclusive. that is $2\cdot 2^{-\binom n2} = 2^{-\binom n2+1}$. And the probability that both colors are represented is the opposite of that.